# Installing and configuring net-snmp on windows

Tags: windows, snmp, net-snmp

Hi I am trying to install NET-SNMP on windows server to use it as SNMP agent. I have a remote server runnning a java thread. The thread is polling SNMP information. I installed 5.7.3 NET-SNMP and my snmpd.conf is as below.

```
createUser myagent MD5 myagentmyagent
rouser myagent auth
```

And when I try snmpwalk command with .1.3.6.1.2.1 oid it works fine.

```
snmpwalk -v 3 -u myagent -A myagentmyagent -l authNoPriv  localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1
```

However when I try to get hrSWRunName with .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.2, it says "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID".

```
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

I did not touch any files under $NET-SNMPDir/share/snmp.
Is there anyone could help me?

Comment: `1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.2` is invalid for GET requests, as you cannot query a column. The correct OID to access an item in the table must be a combination of column OID and the entry index.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for your reply. But I have a CentOS 7 server which NET-SNMP installed. 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.2 works fine on the CentOS Server